# Finding Employee Turnover by Department in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for Employee Turnover By every department per month. My Data consists of Employee ID, Hire Date, Department, Termination Date and HR_Status.

[image]

I want to find the turnover by Month by Division.

**Leavers = Current Month Count taken from TermDate**

**Turnover for particular Month = Current Month Leavers / AVG (Row Count for Last Month and Current Month)**

Previously I asked this question and someone answered it here but it wasn't by group of Division.

[Finding Month on Month Turnover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53816367/finding-month-on-month-turnover/53817175#53817175)

Reproduce

```
structure(list(TerminationDate = structure(c(16921, 16921, 12814, 
13028, 15392, 15160, 15186, NA, 17135, 12788, 14491, NA, 15166, 
15126, 15113, 17060, 13283, 12916, NA, 17905, 15611, 17135, 13299, 
17183, 17256, 12761, 17256, 17256, 14421, 14526, 12892, 17214, 
14526, 14526, 15160, 12863, 12726, 14491, 13010, 16073, 16073, 
13955, 15125, 15317, NA, 15429, 15474, 12843, 15237, 12921), class = "Date"), 
    HireDate = structure(c(759283200, 759283200, 766281600, 773020800, 
    781056000, 781056000, 783216000, 786240000, 787708800, 792201600, 
    792547200, 790732800, 796694400, 802828800, 813715200, 764985600, 
    828316800, 846374400, 848188800, 848361600, 848793600, 850003200, 
    861580800, 867715200, 870134400, 873072000, 875664000, 875664000, 
    876182400, 876700800, 878342400, 878342400, 878515200, 879120000, 
    879724800, 881193600, 881539200, 883612800, 883612800, 883612800, 
    883612800, 883612800, 883612800, 883612800, 883612800, 888710400, 
    888710400, 890697600, 893030400, 893376000), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), HrstatusName = c("Resigned", "Resigned", 
    "Resigned", "Resigned", "Resigned", "Resigned", "Resigned", 
    "Regular", "Resigned", "Resigned", "Resigned", "Regular", 
    "Gross Misconduct", "Resigned", "Resigned", "Deceased", "Resigned", 
    "Resigned", "Regular", "Terminated", "Resigned", "Resigned", 
    "Resigned", "Resigned", "Resigned", "Resigned", "Resigned", 
    "Resigned", "Resigned", "Resigned", "Resigned", "Resigned", 
    "Resigned", "Resigned", "Resigned", "Resigned", "Resigned", 
    "Resigned", "Resigned", "Terminated", "Terminated", "Terminated", 
    "Retired", "Resigned", "Regular", "Resigned", "Resigned", 
    "Resigned", "Resigned", "Resigned"), EmployeeId = c("39bab084", 
    "39bab084", "5664d681", "520d0890", "20d65e2d", "eb8a8d88", 
    "1d30178f", "6dec15c8", "f67d57de", "76fb57f8", "3b33f6f3", 
    "a0a2b4e5", "9aa8d595", "dc820f73", "acace7da", "740ee9ec", 
    "35c81bd8", "f075debf", "5602d50b", "0d2d3f55", "5de0aee6", 
    "30cb76f7", "a9af8af5", "a95d601b", "32cc220d", "c476b80a", 
    "90772765", "90772765", "9c79745a", "ec579cf3", "f152ac4b", 
    "00041e9e", "b261e06b", "0efff3b5", "44db7a6c", "63d42ba4", 
    "38fbc1fa", "9960e29c", "48d52953", "051d8858", "051d8858", 
    "f44b3a8d", "3f17e928", "250c1bac", "68c4baa7", "7c3e5ee1", 
    "e7af1cf7", "cb4236d2", "f85f925b", "432da957"), Division = c("a60c5c5c", 
    "a60c5c5c", "3cc0c23b", "7e23b2d7", "3cc0c23b", "3cc0c23b", 
    "3cc0c23b", "eae5d36f", "c3abc225", "3cc0c23b", "7e23b2d7", 
    "eae5d36f", "3cc0c23b", "7e23b2d7", "eae5d36f", "a60c5c5c", 
    "7e23b2d7", "3cc0c23b", "3cc0c23b", "3cc0c23b", "c3abc225", 
    "c3abc225", "c3abc225", "5d980f59", "c3abc225", "eae5d36f", 
    "c3abc225", "c3abc225", "3cc0c23b", "a60c5c5c", "c3abc225", 
    "eae5d36f", "7e23b2d7", "a60c5c5c", "3cc0c23b", "3cc0c23b", 
    "3cc0c23b", "7e23b2d7", "3cc0c23b", "7e23b2d7", "7e23b2d7", 
    "7e23b2d7", "7e23b2d7", "3cc0c23b", "eae5d36f", "c3abc225", 
    "3cc0c23b", "216743cf", "3cc0c23b", "3cc0c23b")), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000006261ef0>)
```

**Code Tried**

```
library(data.table)

df_leavers <- setDT(df)[, `:=` (TermDate = as.Date(as.character(TermDate)),
                                HireDate = as.Date(as.character(HireDate)))]

df_presences <- copy(df_leavers)

df_leavers <- df_leavers[, TermDate := format(TermDate, "%Y-%m")][!is.na(TermDate), (Leavers = .N), , by = TermDate]

df_presences <- df_presences[, maxTerm := max(TermDate, na.rm = T)][
  is.na(TermDate), TermDate := maxTerm][
    , .(YearMonth = format(seq(HireDate, TermDate, by = "month"), "%Y-%m")), by = 1:nrow(df)][
      , (Presences = .N), by = YearMonth]

df_final <- df_leavers[df_presences, on = .(TermDate = YearMonth)]

setnames(df_final, c("YearMonth", "Leavers", "Presences"))

df_final <- df_final[is.na(Leavers), Leavers := 0][order(YearMonth),][, previousMonth := shift(Presences)][
  is.na(previousMonth), previousMonth := 0][, AvgPresences := (Presences + previousMonth) / 2][
    , Turnover := round(Leavers / AvgPresences, 2)][, "previousMonth" := NULL]
```

It gives me the output correctly except it doesn't give it by Division

**Desired Output**

```
Date         Turnover  Division
2019-01      0.23      XYC
2019-01      0.02      ZYV
```

Comment: I do not see the relation between the sample data and your desired output... are they connected? Where do Division XYC and ZYV come from?

Comment: Oh this is just a sample as I masked the data. 

So this is simple.

Just as you have found count of leavers, now, for each month, divide that count by average of count for last two months and we get turnover, but it should be by Division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you're after.

I made some extra columns so you can comprehend each step.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo) 

df %>%
  mutate(month = as.yearmon(TerminationDate, "%y/%m")) %>%
   group_by(month, Division) %>% 
    tally(name = "leavers") %>% 
      group_by(Division) %>%
       mutate(prevmonth = lag(leavers, order_by = month),
              sum = leavers + prevmonth, 
              turnover = leavers/(sum/2)) %>%
          select(Division, month, leavers, sum, prevmonth, turnover) %>%
            arrange(Division, month)

# A tibble: 36 x 6
# Groups:   Division [7]
   Division month         leavers   sum prevmonth turnover
   <chr>    <S3: yearmon>   <int> <int>     <int>    <dbl>
 1 216743cf Mrz 2005            1    NA        NA   NA    
 2 3cc0c23b Nov 2004            1    NA        NA   NA    
 3 3cc0c23b Jan 2005            2     3         1    1.33 
 4 3cc0c23b Mrz 2005            1     3         2    0.667
 5 3cc0c23b Mai 2005            2     3         1    1.33 
 6 3cc0c23b Aug 2005            1     3         2    0.667
 7 3cc0c23b Jun 2009            1     2         1    1    
 8 3cc0c23b Jul 2011            4     5         1    1.6  
 9 3cc0c23b Sep 2011            1     5         4    0.4  
10 3cc0c23b Dez 2011            1     2         1    1    
# ... with 26 more rows
```

So here I did for `3cc0c23b` in Jan 2005:

[image].

That seems to fit you explanation of

> Turnover for particular Month = Current Month Leavers / AVG (Row Count for Last Month and Current Month)

But especially the "previous month" part requires further information. Do you mean the previous month in your dataset? Because there are many months with no data. My solution considers the last month in your dataset. So the turnover of the first month in each division, as well as division with only one month have NA as turnover.

If you mean the previous month in the calendar, and his absence from the dataset meaning no leavers in this month please indicate.

UPDATE:
This is weird.. In the CRAN documentation of `dplyr`

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/dplyr.pdf

`tally()`and `count()` have the argument `name =` to assign a name to the new column, which works for me.

But here:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/tally

it says:

> There is currently no way to control the output variable name - if you need to change the default, you'll have to write the summarise() yourself.

And it doesn't work for you. Is this a version problem? I'm using dplyr_0.8.0.1

But well, then let's do this:

```
df %>%
  mutate(month = as.yearmon(TerminationDate, "%y/%m")) %>%
  group_by(month, Division) %>%
  summarise(leavers = n()) %>% 
  group_by(Division) %>%
  mutate(prevmonth = lag(leavers, order_by = month),
         sum = leavers + prevmonth, 
         turnover = leavers/(sum/2)) %>%
  select(Division, month, leavers, sum, prevmonth, turnover) %>%
  arrange(Division, month)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am going to test it shortly.

Comment: I am getting this error, Do you have idea why? `Error in tally(., name = "leavers") : unused argument (name = "leavers")`

Comment: is the `tally()` function masked by another function? Try `dplyr::tally(name = "leavers")`

Comment: weird. made an update with `count()` instead of `tally()` and grouping inside `count()`.

Comment: are you defining `leavers` somewhere before hand? with the update, I am getting `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'leavers' not found.`

Comment: I made an update. Can you tell me what version of `dplyr` you're using? Just do `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Phew! This works now! Btw My dplyr version is `dplyr_0.7.8`

Comment: awesome! So it was a version problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190420/discussion-between-rana-usman-and-humpelstielzchen).